# Django : Django paths not working as expected

Tags: html, css, django, url

I have a project . I have to reference a json file . My code which is the flashcard.html file :

```
{%include 'header.html' %}

<style>
{%include 'css/flashcard.css' %}
{%include 'css/header.css' %}


</style>
<div id="content" style="width: 100%; position: relative;"></div>

<i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 95%; font-size: 50px;" id="next"></i>

<i class="fas fa-caret-left" style="position: absolute; top: 20%; left:5%; font-size: 50px;" id="back"></i>

<script>
    let mydata = {%include 'data.json' %}
    let frontSideFront = true
    let cardNum = 0
    let totalCards = 2


    //var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i = 0 ; i < totalCards ; i++ ){
        frontSideFront = true
        $("#content").append(`
           <div class="card-container" id="${i}">
                <div class="front">${mydata['questions'][i]}</div>
                <div class="back">sd</div>
           </div>
           `)
    }

    for(var m = 0 ; m < totalCards ; m++ ){
        if (m !== cardNum) {
            $(`#${m}`).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    }

    $("#next").click(function (e) {
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('position', 'absolute');
        cardNum++
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('visibility', 'visible');
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('position', 'relative');
    });

     $("#back").click(function (e) {
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('position', 'absolute');
        cardNum--
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('visibility', 'visible');
        $(`#${cardNum}`).css('position', 'relative');
    });

    $(".card-container").click((e)=>{
        if(frontSideFront){
            frontSideFront = false
            $(".front").css({
                "transform": "rotateY(-180deg)",
            })
            $(".back").css({
                "transform": "rotateY(0deg)",
            })
        }else{
            frontSideFront = true
            $(".front").css({
                "transform": "rotateY(0deg)",
            })
            $(".back").css({
                "transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
            })
        }
    })





</script>
```

The code is to create a flashcard. But the problem is that my data.json file is not being accessed . I even tried absolute paths.Like:

`D:\anshu\python\uceed-website\venv\uceedWebsite\data.json`

and even

`../../../data.json`

and :

`../../data.json`

and:
`./data.json`

.

My file structure :
[image]

You can ask any doubts and questions .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using `JsonResponse()`? Load your JSON data from views and the return it as `JsonResponse`

Comment: Hmmm.... Thanks for trying to answer , but my views.py file returns a render template. And my need is a bit different for this project .I don't think it would work . And I moved to flask because of it's api's.FYI my data is created in views .